# How To get current click event text from bootstrap multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery

am trying to get the current clicked option text from a multi select.but on change event is only working. on click event not working please check

```
$('#myoption').change(function () {
alert($(this).children("option").text());
});
```

Comment: Would you provide your HTML for find the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

> [onChange](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options-onChange): A function which is triggered on the change event of the options. Note that the event is not triggered when selecting or deselecting options using the select and deselect methods provided by the plugin.

```js
$('#example-getting-started').multiselect({
    onChange: function(option, checked, select) {
        console.log('Changed option ' + $(option).val() + '.');
    }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css">
<script src="https://rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <select id="example-getting-started" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
        <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
        <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
        <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
        <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
        <option value="onions">Onions</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: when clicking on each option it needs to alert the text. thats iam trying

Comment: @kannanD.S  If you are using this plugin, running the snippet you can see the message text in the snippet console when you click an option. Let me know. Consider to add bootstrap as tag to your question

Comment: the same plugin iam using.But insted of check box iam using glyphicons

Answer (score 0):

you could do this:

```
$('#myoption').change(function () {
console.log($(this).children("option").filter(":selected").text());
});
```